# If I provided incorrect subdomain name during Kabanero Foundation installation, how to fix it?

Tags: kabanero

I provided incorrect subdomain name during Kabanero Foundation installation on OKD. Now my Application-->Routes are wrong. How to fix that?

For Kabanero Landing Page, my link is: https://kabanero-landing-kabanero./
I tried https://kabanero-landing-kabanero./ but I get

Application is not available
The application is currently not serving requests at this endpoint. It may not have been started or is still starting.

Expected: Kabanero Landing Page
Actual: Application is not available
The application is currently not serving requests at this endpoint. It may not have been started or is still starting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There really is no good way to fix it. There is not a good manner to change the routes automatically.  Assuming you are early in your install, you should be able to clone the `0.2.0` (if you installed 0.2.0) support scripts from https://github.com/kabanero-io/kabanero-foundation/tree/0.2.0/scripts  and run the `uninstall-kabanero-foundation.sh` script to remove the foundation and reinstall.  You should be able to keep the OKD install that you have done.

If there are enough people that hit this, I can put a requirement in place to provide an update script to change this value and restart.